# ExtJS with Jawr appears to be messing with encoding settings

Tags: extjs, character-encoding, jawr

I'm having trouble with some German strings being encoded incorrectly on response.  The project is setup in Grails using ExtJS and Jawr.  All strings are stored in a .properties file, which are translated on a per language basis.  The German strings include a character that needs to be encoded in utf-8.  Strings encoded using g:strings, work correctly.  The g:strings passed through the Jawr are not displaying correctly.  I tried setting the jawr encoding by setting jawr.charset.name='utf-8' in the Config.groovy file, but that did not fix it.  My understand is that the jawr charset should use the grails setting when possible, which is currently set using:

grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"

I tried tracing down the html using firebug, but did all encodings appear to be utf-8.  My only theory is that the string is being encoded incorrectly by the jawr.  Any ideas on where I should look?  I'm currently using Jawr-3.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found outside of forum.  Problem was in local run of grails using run-app.  Deployed version worked fine.